# jQuery: Splash page animation sequence ending with a URL jump

Tags: jquery, url, animation

I am creating a simple splash page with the following sequence:

1. Fade in elements
2. Wait 5 seconds
3. Fade out elements
4. Launch new page

I can get steps 1 through 3 to work properly in sequence.

However, as soon as I add a url redirection to my chain (step 4), it runs steps 1 to 3 super quickly and jumps. Here's the code I'm using:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.splash p { background: yellow; display: none; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.fn.go_homebase = function() {
    var url = "homebase.html";
    $(location).attr('href',url);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.splash p').fadeIn('slow').delay(5000).fadeOut('slow').go_homebase();
});
</script>
</head>
<body class="splash">
<p>Splash Page!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a proper and better way I should be doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should call `go_homebase` in the complete callback of `fadeOut`, e.g.:

```
$('.splash p').fadeIn('slow').delay(5000).fadeOut('slow', function() { $(this).go_homebase(); });
```

Comment: Awesome, that worked and is more simple to execute! Once again, I just made it more difficult for myself!

Answer (score 1):

This works perfectly for me.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.splash p').fadeIn(1500).delay(5000).fadeOut(2000,
        function() { window.location = "http://google.com"; });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
$('.splash p').fadeIn('slow').delay(5000).fadeOut('slow', 
  function(){ $(this).go_homebase()}
);
```

You need to call the redirect function as a callback, when the last animation has finished.